# Declare read-only object properties in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, properties, private, public

Here is the class with initializer:

```
class MyUser
  attr_reader :id

  def initialize(parameters)
    @id = parameters['id']
    @login = parameters['login']
    @balance = parameters['balance']
    @info = parameters['info']
  end
end
```

Its usage:

```
usr = MyUser.new(the_hash)

puts usr.inspect
```

And the output of inspect:

`#<MyUser:0x3bcd318 @id="1", @login="TS1", @balance="0", @info="blah blah blah">`

I want that `MyUser` will look like a normal class when inspecting it, with .id, .login, .balance, and .info properties instead of @id, @login, @balance, and @info. How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "normal class"? It is normal class with its instance variables.

Comment: @MarekLipka I think OP meant regular class by so...

Comment: @ArupRakshit so now what do you mean by "regular class"? :)

Comment: @MarekLipka Regular class is a class, for example from which you can create instances of it (as an example). But you wouldn't be able to do the same on class like `singleton_class`..

Comment: I thought that the task of `.inspect` method is to show all public members of an object. Probably I was wrong. What I really need is an encapsulation of attributes so that they could only be read through accessors like `my_obj.id`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're looking for, [`inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is doing what `inspect` does.  It doesn't call methods for you, and the Ruby language doesn't really have "properties", you're just using `attr_reader` to generate an accessor method for the instance variable.

You could of course override the `inspect` method if you wanted to, what's your goal?

Comment: I am dam sure OP was looking for such an overriding on `#inspect`. You are on the right track, just go ahead and complete the answer..